# xautomation xte key for + used in autostart

Tags: raspbian, chromium, kiosk

I'm trying to send Ctrl+ (to zoom in on a browser) but can't find the correct key for +.
I've tried NumPadAdd,+ and a few other variants. Any ideas what the key name is?

I've added the following to /home/pi/.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart in Jessie with Pixel. The URL is a site that requires a login. The login is saved but requires 'Return' to accept the credentials. It then needs zooming to 125% (Ctrl+ x2)

```
############## Browser auto launch ################### 
# Comment out the line below with a hash, after setting the Chrome-browser launch page 
#@leafpad /home/pi/.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart 
@chromium-browser --kiosk --disable-restore-session-state --display=:0 http://www.google.co.uk

sleep 20 && xte 'key Return' -x:0
sleep 5 && xte 'keydown Control_L' 'key NumPadAdd' 'keyup Control_L' -x:0
```

Comment: Turns out that zooming can also be achieved by holding down Ctrl and rolling the mouse wheel. So the xte options I'm after are MouseWheelUp or NumberPadAdd - rolling the wheel up twice or pressing the plus key (numberpad or above the = key).

Comment: *** SOLVED - delayed remote zoom achieved *** 
sleep 2 && xte 'keydown Control_L' 'key equal' 'keyup Control_L' -x:0

Comment: Mouse wheel up/4 down/5:: $ xte 'mouseclick 4'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answers myself (with help!).
(Ctrl + plus) = $ xte 'keydown Control_L' 'key equal' 'keyup Control_L'
(Mousewheel up/down) = xte 'mousebutton 4' 'mousebutton 5'
Where 4 is scroll up and 5 is scroll down.

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.